# database query in rmarkdown/quarto document works in R chunk but fails in sql chunk

Tags: sql, r, r-markdown, quarto, exasol

I work in an rmarkdown / quarto document querying a database (Exasol) with read-only access. This works fine if executed in an R chunk as follows.

````
```{r} 
conn <- exasol::dbConnect( drv = "exa", exahost = "my_host_url", 
          uid = Sys.getenv("EXASOL_USER"), pwd = Sys.getenv("EXASOL_PWD") )

query <- "SELECT * FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE LIMIT 10"
df <- exasol::dbGetQuery(conn, query)
```
````

Now, I try to run the same query in an `sql` chunk.

````
```{sql connection=conn}
SELECT * FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE LIMIT 10
```
````

However, I get the following error message.

```
Using Schema from statement: "MY_SCHEMA"
Transaction rolled back.
Error in exa.readData(res$connection, query, ...) : 
  Could not receive header
In addition: Warning message:
In .EXAExecStatement(con = conn, stmt = statement, schema = schema,  :
  42500 -6818256 [EXASOL][EXASolution driver]insufficient privileges for creating table (Session: 1741969101333790720)[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'create table "SUS_ANALYTICS".TEMP_791648_CREATED_BY_R as (SELECT * FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE LIMIT 10
)'
Error in exa.readData(res$connection, query, ...) : 
  Could not execute SQL: '42000' -6811776' [EXASOL][EXASolution driver]object "MY_SCHEMA"."TEMP_791648_CREATED_BY_R" not found [line 1, column 23] (Session: 1741969101333790720)'
Failed to execute SQL chunk
```

I have read access only. So, the crucial information appears to be `insufficient privileges for creating table`. It appears the engine tries to create a temporary table and fails.

- **Why does this happen as the R chunk works without these problems?**
- And, more important: **Is there a way to make the sql chunk work?** :)

*PS. Sorry, I do not know how to make this example reproducible.*

Comment: The temporary table is created here: https://github.com/exasol/r-exasol/blob/2e3aa43676e0871285c723f0873b8112e45ab034/R/EXADBI-query.R#L68 it looks like this is done to get some metadata about the query result like column names. I don't see an easy way to circumvent this.

Answer (score 2):

As already described in the comments and other answers, the problem is caused by Exasol trying to create a table when using `DBI::dbSendQuery`. There is, however, an easy workaround for this. Just set the sql chunk parameter `max.print = -1`. This will cause the knitr sql engine to use `DBI::dbGetQuery` instead if `DBI::dbSendQuery`. As `DBI::dbGetQuery` does not try to create a (temporary) table, the problem is evaded.

*Example*

````
```{sql connection=conn, max.print=-1}
SELECT * FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE LIMIT 10
```
````

**Why?**

The following code is from [lines 616 ff. of the knitr sql engine](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/59cf48204a866a2046f00ff6f8a8ca386e2cf563/R/engine.R#L616)

```
  data = tryCatch({
    if (is_sql_update_query(query)) {
      DBI::dbExecute(conn, query)
      NULL
    } else if (is.null(varname) && max.print > 0) {
      # execute query -- when we are printing with an enforced max.print we
      # use dbFetch so as to only pull down the required number of records
      res = DBI::dbSendQuery(conn, query)
      data = DBI::dbFetch(res, n = max.print)
      DBI::dbClearResult(res)
      data

    } else {
      if (length(params) == 0) {
        DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, query)
      } else {
        # If params option is provided, parameters are not interplolated
        DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, sql, params = params)
      }
    }
    ...
```

The first `else if` statement is the relevant part: If you set `max.print` to a value equal or smaller than `0`, it will èxecute `DBI::dbGetQuery` instead of `DBI::dbSendQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

sirain is right. Currently, r-exasol needs to create the temporary table to implement the paging of the DBI interface. With that, you need the write permission to run the sql chunk.